# Groovy. Sort array of maps by key of a nested map within

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

How do I write some groovy script to return an array of names (`name`) sorted by the `created_at` key that is nested within the `commit` key?

Using [this](https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/gitlab-org%2Fgitlab-ce/repository/tags) as sample data:

```
[
{"name":"v10.8.0-rc13",
"message":"Version v10.8.0-rc13",
"target":"171b50a40984c358a07c7e37ee95f8d788718198",
"commit":
 {
 "id":"1b3911c3cc8e72cc93370a90a597e2a0b944bcc2",
 "short_id":"1b3911c3",
 "title":"Update VERSION to 10.8.0-rc13",
 "created_at":"2018-05-18T12:43:58.000+01:00",       <------ I WANT TO SORT BY THIS 
 "parent_ids":["a7090d00098a4acc03cfc2b01df8019c918bd0bc"],
 "message":"Update VERSION to 10.8.0-rc13\n",
 "author_name":"Filipa Lacerda",
 "author_email":"filipa@gitlab.com",
 "authored_date":"2018-05-18T12:43:58.000+01:00",
 "committer_name":"Filipa Lacerda",
 "committer_email":"filipa@gitlab.com",
 "committed_date":"2018-05-18T12:43:58.000+01:00"
  },
"release":null
},
.
.
.
]
```

So far, I'm using something like this to get the list of unsorted names:

```
List<String> tags= new ArrayList<String>()

def url="curl -X GET http://blah_blah"
def payload = url.execute().text
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def response = slurper.parseText(payload)

for(item in response)
{
   tags.add(item.name)
}

println(tags)
```

In this case, `response` is of type `java.util.ArrayList`

and `response[0]` is of type `groovy.json.internal.LazyMap`

All the examples I have found so far use the `.sort` or `.SortBy` methods that don't work on a `LazyMap`. *****UPDATE**** I don't think this is a true* statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of names of tags from such structure, you can use Groovy's spread operator:

```
def tags = response*.name
```

It can be simplified to:

```
def tags = response.name
```

and this is just an equivalent of:

```
def tags = response.collect { it.name }
```

Now, if you expect this list to be sorted by `commit.created_at` key, you can call `.sort {}` method before using spread operator, e.g.

```
def tags = response.sort { it.commit.created_at }.name
```

It will sort list of names in ascending order. If you are interested in descending order then you can negate the body of sort method:

```
def tags = response.sort { !it.commit.created_at }.name
```

Below you can find a full example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/gitlab-org%2Fgitlab-ce/repository/tags".toURL().text

def response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def tags = response.sort { it.commit.created_at }.name

println tags
```

Output:

```
[v10.7.0, v10.8.0.pre, v10.7.1, v10.5.8, v10.6.5, v10.7.2, v10.8.0-rc1, v10.7.3, v10.8.0-rc2, v10.8.0-rc3, v10.8.0-rc4, v10.8.0-rc6, v10.8.0-rc5, v10.8.0-rc7, v10.8.0-rc8, v10.8.0-rc9, v10.8.0-rc10, v10.8.0-rc11, v10.8.0-rc12, v10.8.0-rc13]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Szymon! I *think* I got it to work using this:
`response.sort { a,b -> a.commit.created_at <=> b.commit.created_at }`
Does that sound right?

Comment: @frakman1 This is an equivalent of `response.sort { it.commit.created_at }`. The only difference is that `{ a,b -> a.commit.created_at <=> b.commit.created_at }` is a closure that represents Comparator object.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and clear explanation. I get it now.

Comment: It worked like a charm!, thank you